# Unable to append to jQuery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I've been banging my head against this for some time now. I can't find any way of appending this  tag to it's parent. The variable seems to be defined any time I check it in a debugger but the append simply doesn't occur. It only seems to work if I do not pass the variable and instead query for the parent inline.

```
function AdType($parentObj, adSlot)
{
    this.$parentObj = $($parentObj);
    this.adSlot = adSlot;
}
AdType.prototype.display = function()
{
    var insert = document.createElement("ins");
    insert.className = "adsbygoogle";

    this.$parentObj.append(insert);
};    
AdType.prototype.remove = function()
{
    this.$parentObj.empty();
};


var Ads = {
    mobile :  new AdType($("#mobile-ad"), "555"),

    display : function () {
        if (Display.get() == 'mobile'){
            this.mobile.display();
        }
    }
};

Ads.display();
```

Comment: What happens when you console.log(this.$parentObj); ?

Comment: I get an object descriptor starting with: [selector: "#mobile-ad", context: document, constructor: function, init: function, jquery: "1.7.2"…]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I notice is that your `AdType` object is a property of `Ads`. The codes seem to work when I replace `Ads.display()` with `Ads.mobile.display()`. Also, to improve code readability, there is no need to repeat those `$` symbol in your function argument.

Take a look at this stack snippet, where I was able to append an `<a>` tag to your `AdType`.

```js
function AdType(parentObj, adSlot)
{
    this.parentObj = parentObj;
    this.adSlot = adSlot;
}
AdType.prototype.display = function()
{
    this.parentObj.append('<a href="#">I got appended!</a>');
};    
AdType.prototype.remove = function()
{
    this.$parentObj.empty();
};


var Ads = {
    mobile:  new AdType($("#mobile-ad"), "555")
};
Ads.mobile.display();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="mobile-ad"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the style note! I've been fretting over the proper style to use when incorporating jQuery. Good to know that the problem lies within the Ads call to the AdType function! I was definitely focused in the wrong place. So why is it that the function inside of Ads is unable to call the function inside of AdType?

Comment: @NathanielStevens Because `Ads` is a javascript object with its own `prototype` property, which is different from that of `AdType`. Your `display` and `remove` functions are added to `AdType.prototype`.

Comment: But in the code that I posted there is a display function defined for the Ads object.

Comment: @NathanielStevens In your codes, `display` was defined as a function of `AdType`.